# Авторизация по LDAP: похоже, проблема с сертификатами

Tags: java, ldap

Коллеги, привет.

Мне необходимо авторизовывать пользователей по LDAP. Для этого у меня есть сертификаты, которые я добавил в keystore java следующим образом на тестовом стенде:

```
keytool -import -alias ca -file CA01_root.crt -keystore cacerts -storepass changeit
```

Хранилище по адресу:

```
cd /usr/java/jdk-11.0.3/lib/security/
```

После этого, всё заработало. Теперь пришло время сделать то же самое на продуктивном стенде, я беру те же сертификаты, добавляю таким же образом в keystore, но при попытке авторизоваться мне выдаёт следующее:

> 2019-10-09 16:03:11.229  INFO 19023 --- [nio-9090-exec-1]
>   r.p.h.c.CustomAuthenticationProvider     : url:
>   ldaps://example.ru:636/
>   org.springframework.ldap.CommunicationException: simple bind failed:
>   example.ru:636; nested exception is
>   javax.naming.CommunicationException: simple bind failed:
>   example.ru:636 [Root exception is
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target]

Подскажите, в чём проблема? Не подходит сертификат, или я поместил его не туда, или нужно было перезапустить какой-нибудь сервис?

UPD. Заметил, что на первом сервере (в котором всё работает) есть два пути, по которым есть java: `/usr/java/jdk-11.0.3/lib/security` и `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.3.7-0.el7_6.x86_64/lib/security` (причём, скопированные файлы лежат по обоим путям, что позволяет сделать вывод, что это просто разные пути к одной папке), а на втором сервере первого пути нет, есть только `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.4.11-0.el7_6.x86_64` так вот на втором сервере за неимением других вариантов сертификаты были установлены по имеющемуся пути

Comment: У Вас на сервере, наверное, другая версия Java? Такая ошибка обычно бывает когда корневой сертификат удостоверяющего центра отсутствует в списке доверенных сертификатов в JRE/JDK

Comment: Заметил, что на первом сервере (в котором всё работает) есть два пути, по которым есть java: `/usr/java/jdk-11.0.3/lib/security` и `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.3.7-0.el7_6.x86_64/lib/security` (причём, скопированные файлы лежат по обоим путям, что позволяет сделать вывод, что это просто разные пути к одной папке), а на втором сервере первого пути нет, есть только `/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.4.11-0.el7_6.x86_64` так вот на втором сервере за неимением других вариантов сертификаты были установлены по имеющемуся пути

Comment: Ну, как самый простой вариант, можно просто скопировать файлик cacerts из  `/usr/java/jdk-11.0.3/lib/security и /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-11.0.3.7-0.el7_6.x86_64/lib/security` с сервера где все работает на сервер где не работает